# What are some examples of formally large graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, computer-science

Small graphs are contrasted with large graphs on page 9 of *Category Theory for Computer Science* by Barr and Wells.

The definition of a **small** graph is pretty straightforward. *src* and *tgt* functions map edge labels to node labels in a finite set. However, what would be an example of a **large** graph. The book briefly mentions a graph of all the sets which kind of sounds like the graph analog of classes.

TL;DR: What does a large graph look like?

**UPDATE**
Here's the definition:

> Formally, to specify a graph, you must specify its nodes (or objects)
> and its arrows. Each arrow must have a specific source (or domain)
> node and target (or codomain) node...We will systematically denote the collection of nodes of a graph *G* by $G_0$
> and the collection of arrows by $G_1$, and similarly with other letters (*H* has
> nodes $H_0$, *C* has nodes $C_0$, and so on). The nodes form the zero-dimensional
> part of the graph and the arrows the one-dimensional part....
> A graph that has a set of nodes and arrows is a small
> graph; otherwise, it is a large graph

Comment: Could you maybe copy the definitions of the textbook into your post for reference?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can take the category of all sets and realize it as a directed multigraph where the nodes are sets and the edges are set morphisms. This is "large" since the collection of nodes is a proper class.

Comment: @bobeyt6 Here's a link to the page: https://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf#page=27

Comment: Did you understand that you are asking about what something that contains infinitely many nodes (vertices) "looks like"?  Per Douglas Adams, "Space is big..." [Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, Intro](https://sites.google.com/site/h2g2theguide/intro)

Answer (score 0):

A large graph looks just like a graph, except it might have a proper class of vertices and/or a proper class of edges. A somewhat simpler example than the graph of all sets is the graph whose vertices are all ordinals with edges from any $\alpha$ to its successor. This is just the disjoint union of a proper class number of graphs like this: $\bullet\to\bullet\to\bullet\to\cdots.$ Anyway, yes, you seem to have the right idea.